# Issues in making Routes in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, navigation

I am making a project and getting some problem in managing routes. My Frontend is divided in two parts. One For the Client side and onother is the admin-panel for handling the Client side. For example if I add some Blog from admin-panel then it shows on Client-side. Admin-Panel is for my team to handle the website. Suppose Users will visit on my website at "www.mywebsite.com' and I want that if I enter "www.mywebsite.com/admin" then Admin-panel and Admin-components should open instead of Nav-Components.
How Do I achieve this conditional routing?

Here is the App.js

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Landing from "./components/Landing";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Teams from "./components/Team";
import Events from "./components/Events";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import Blog from "./components/Blog";
import ContactUs from "./components/Contact";
import ComingSoon from "./components/ComingSoon";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import EventInfo from "./components/EventInfo";
import AdminNavbar from "./admin-panel/AdmiNavbar";
import Login from "./admin-panel/Login";
import Eventadd from "./admin-panel/Eventadd";
import Blogadd from "./admin-panel/Blogadd";
import Dashboard from "./admin-panel/Dashboard";


const NavComponents = () => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/events" exact component={Events} />
        <Route path="/team" exact component={Teams} />
        <Route path="/blog" exact component={Blog} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={ContactUs} />
        <Route path="/comingsoon" exact component={ComingSoon} />
        <Route path="/eventinfo/:eventName" exact component={EventInfo} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};

const AdminPanel = () =>{

  return(
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin/Eventadd" exact component={Eventadd}/>
        <Route path="/admin/Blogadd" exact component={Blogadd}/>
        <Route path="/admin/DashBoard" exact component={Dashboard}/>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  
  
  render() {
    
    return (
      <>
      {window.location.pathname=="/"?"": <Navbar />}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
          <NavComponents />
        </Switch>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are all the "admin" routes nested in "/admin"? You could have a main "switch" that render one or the other of your client/admin routes. Do the admin routes require any sort of authentication or user roles in order to access?

Comment: Yes there will be a login page on route "/admin" for authentication of admins

Comment: All admin components are nested in "/admin" as in above code

Comment: Can you please tell the switch condition or changes I need to make in above code?

Comment: I agree with Li Sam's answer below, there's no reason to split all these routes, they can all be rendered into a single `Switch` component. I suggest you review the [Auth Workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) demo and implement "AdminRoute" component that handles checking if person has admin access. We can help if you provide a bit more context how you are determining this access.

Answer (score 0):

I assume if users enter your website through "www.mywebsite.com/admin" link, you want to re-route them to "/admin/DashBoard" route? The admin dashboard doesn't show because, it only returns the route with EXACT match. It's possible to

A) Add an additional path to handle the routing

`<Route path=["/admin/DashBoard", "/admin"] exact component={Dashboard}/>`

B) Add a Redirect for admin if you prefer to keep the route as /admin/dashboard

`` <Redirect exact from="/admin" to={`/admin/dashboard`} /> ``

Edit: (Most importantly)

Also, noticed that you did not include the admin into the main  router. You don't need to separate the admin from nav. Suggest to read on the document
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

`Switch renders the first child <Route> or <Redirect> that matches the location.`

Overall, it should be combined like this

```
<Switch>
...user paths
...admin paths
</Switch>
```

Comment: Actually my problem is that whenever I enter "www.mywebsite.com/admin" is shows error because I am not rendering my admin components. I want to render them as AdminPanel in similar way as I have rendered NavComponents above. How to do that?

Comment: Updated the post to include the rendering issue that you highlighted. You don't have to separate out the NavComponent and AdminPanel. Combine them inside one Switch. If you do want to do extra processing for Admin routes, then you could do a wrapper component for your admin routes

Comment: But if someone will enter "www.mywebsite.com/admin/dashboard" will it not open the dashboard directly without the authentication step at "www.mywebsite.com/admin"?

Comment: If you want to have an authentication step, you can create a component for /admin route and move all the admin routes into that component. Sort of like a child route using the same technique. E.g ```<Switch><Route path="admin/panel"/> etc```